# read non latin char from json string in java

Tags: java, json, unicode

i have a json string in a txt file, non latin character are printed like this �����
i need to print them in arabic or french (à,é..) not queqtion marks

```
data==new String(proc.getPrettyJSON().getBytes(), "UTF-8") ;
```

the result is the same

json sample:

```
"PersonalDetails": {
        "BirthDate": "19960321",
        "FullName": "SMITH<<�����",
        "OtherNames": [
            "MARY<<����"
        ],  
    },
```

Comment: Looks to me like the json simply contains invalid characters and there's no way to convert them to anything sensible.

Comment: Please add a sample of the JSON content.

Comment: JSON has to be encoded in Unicode. Using something else is not valid.

Comment: Is it correct in the text file? Either way, are you *sure* it's encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: I'm assuming that `proc.getPrettyJSON()` returns a `String`. That means that `getBytes()` uses your default charset which probably isn't UTF-8. It then doesn't matter that you create a `String` using UTF-8 because the damage has already been done. But if my assumption is correct - why use `String` -> `byte[]` -> `String` conversion and not just use `proc.getPrettyJSON()`?

Comment: What Rob said.  Don’t call getBytes(), that’s just making the problem worse.  If the string doesn’t already contain valid characters, fix the code that reads and creates `proc` in the first place.  (The JSON should have been sent, and read, as UTF-8.)

Comment: when i use proc.getPrettyJSON() iget the same result